# My 'scanf' loop doesn't stop; while condition is not working

Tags: c, scanf

I was supposed to do this exercise: Write a program in C to print a frequency chart on the screen.
Input and output: The program receives as input a sequence of triples (number, frequency, character). For each sequence it should print a slash, producing a graph as in the example below.

Example For input

```
(5,12, -) (4,17, -) (2,1, -) (1,19, +)
```

the program should print

```
  5 | ------------ 12
  4 | ----------------- 17
  2 | -
  1 | +++++++++++++++++++ 19
```

I realize that if I put a space before the sentence in the scanf function, it works very well, but the program desdon't end when it was expected

```
int main()
{
    int x, b, i, u;
    char n;

    do{
        u = scanf(" (%d,%d,%c)", &x, &b, &n);
        printf("%d |", x);
        for (i = 0; i < b; i++){
            printf("%c", n);
        }
        printf(" %d\n", b);
    }while(u == 3);
}
```

It was expected that, when the scanf don't read the 3 things it was supposed to, the while loop ends and the program is finished. But, when it happens, he still waiting for a new input. How do I fix that?

Comment: you should exit as soon as `scanf` does not return `3`; however actually you go on to do the `printf` statements before testing this

Comment: `5.12` uses a `'.'` and `" (%d,%d,%c)"` uses a `,`.

Comment: Test the result of `scanf()` before trying to use values.  When `scanf()` fails, it leaves the character that caused the failure in the input buffer.

Answer (score 1):

just check for the returned value of u and then use an if condition. This shold stop the while loop and exit the program

```
int main()
{
int x, b, i, u;
char n;


do{
    u = scanf(" (%d,%d,%c)", &x, &b, &n);
    if(u == 3){
        printf("%d |", x);
        for (i = 0; i < b; i++){
            printf("%c", n);
        }
        printf(" %d\n", b);
    }

}while(u == 3);
```

Comment: It would be better to use `while ((u = scanf(" (%d.%d, %c)", &x, &b, &n)) == 3)`, which has a number of fixes in it — top-testing the loop; dot instead of comma; skip space before punctuation.

Comment: Actually, it didn't work :( it stills waiting a new input when u !=3